# How to EJB 3.1 Deployment in Tomcat 5.5.x

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, openejb

I have hosting plan which supports

i) Tomcat - 5.5.xSupport

ii) JDK - 1.6.x Support

iii) JSP/servlet - 2.0 Support

Am I able to deploy EJB 3.1 on this setup? I've heard that Tomcat does not support EJBs, but hopefully there is a workaround. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache TomEE was previously the openEJB project if i am not mistaken. You can use the openEJB libraries provided to deploy ejbs on your tomcat instance. More on how to setup can be found at the followinglink:

http://openejb.codehaus.org/tomcat.html

Comment: Thanks for the answering but i have an also question is that possible to use EJB as locally means using it on same JVM in Tomcat ??? is it posible ???

Comment: Yes that is correct. This is what is achieved through Open EJB

Answer (score 3):

That's right, Tomcat is *just* a servlet container, thus you can deploy servlets and JSPs, but not EJBs. You need an application server like JBoss or Glassfish.

There is also an [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) project built on top of Tomcat and probably you can embed some lightweight EJB container inside Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the answering but i have an also question is that possible to use EJB as locally means using it on same JVM in Tomcat ??? is it posible ???