# What should i do to use EJB 3.1 in Apache Tomcat 5.0 web server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1, openejb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to EJB 3.1 Deployment in Tomcat 5.5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440421/how-to-ejb-3-1-deployment-in-tomcat-5-5-x)

> Blockquote

Any buddy please help me i have an web space with apache tomcat 5.0 jsp 2.0 and jvm 1.6
and i want to use ejb in my project so please tell me what should i do that i can use ejb 3.1 in my web space which have these resources listed below

```
i) Tomcat - 5.5.xSupport
ii)JDK - 1.6.x Support
iii)JSP/servlet - 2.0 Support
```

so how can i use EJB with web application with this available resources i mean what should i do to these things

Please Help me...!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304757/how-to-deploy-ejb-3-or-web-application-on-tomcat#4304872) says, try [OpnEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/), but go for JBoss or Glassfish if you can. Tomcat is a JSP container and therefore not meant to this kind of use. EJB run on Application servers.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, go download JBoss AS or GlassFish.
Tomcat implements just the web container part of Java EE

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible and in some cases I prefer the option of using a lightweight container instead of a more heavy weight application server. Having said this though the version of Tomcat your using is too old and won't work anyway without some serious messing about with the container (changing some JARs that come preinstalled with Tomcat), even with that I'm not sure it will work.